# Slider in Flex should control variable in AS3-Class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, binding

I have a problem: In my flex-app there is a slider that should change a variable inside a AS3-Object. How do you realize that?
It's no problem to control the slider with the variable, but I want it the other way :)

Answer (score 2):

So you have a variable in, let's say, ActionScript:

```
[Bindable]
private var sliderVal:Number = 0;
```

Now you need a method for setting the slider from an event:

```
private function changeSlider(event:SliderEvent) : void {
  sliderVal = HSlider(event.currentTarget).value;
}
```

Then you need an event listener in your MXML tag to call the function to set the value:

```
<mx:HSlider change="changeSlider(event)"/>
```

Comment: @thomas: If that solved your problem, please consider clicking the checkmark to accept the answer. It will mark you as a good SO citizen and help ensure that your future questions are well received here.

Answer (score 1):

Does two-way binding solve your problem?

```
<mx:Something attr="@{as3property}"/>
```